# Why does typescript allow this kind of circular reference when using generic types?

Tags: typescript, type-parameter

Why does typescript not complain about the definition of the Document interface below. It seems like a circular reference. How can a type parameter of "Document" be supplied while writing the definition of the Document interface? And how will I ever be able to create a Document object (seems like an infinite circular reference)

```
 interface ValueObject<T> {
  value: T;
  validate(): Boolean
}

interface Document extends ValueObject<Document> {
    value: Document
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the correct Document type? There is one from node.

Comment: Where does this definition come from? And note that the DOM defines a `Document` interface, so in a project with DOM types loaded, this augments the existing interface.

Comment: Side note: [Don't use `Boolean`, use `boolean`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).

Comment: Finally: Why *shouldn't* TypeScript allow circular definitions? Most programming languages also allow infinite loops, but we don't generally write them (er, not on purpose :-D ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding a implementation that compiles is trivial (I renamed `Document` to `FooDocument` to avoid the browser-side `Document`-type)

```js
 interface ValueObject<T> {
  value: T;
  validate(): Boolean
}

interface FooDocument extends ValueObject<FooDocument> {
    value: FooDocument
}

class Foo implements FooDocument {
  value: FooDocument;

  constructor() {
    this.value = new Foo();
  }

  public validate() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now, this is obviously going to end in an endless loop of new Foos being created. However, consider this slightly altered example:

```
class Foo implements FooDocument {
  value: FooDocument;

  constructor(x?: FooDocument) {
    if (x == undefined) {
      this.value = new Foo(this);
      console.log(1);
    } else {
      this.value = x;
      console.log(2);
    }
  }

  public validate() {
    return true;
  }
}

new Foo();
```

Now the Foo constructor is called without a parameter, which then calls the constructor with a parameter, such that in the end the constructor is called twice. This program therefore does not only fulfill your type definition, but also terminates without an endless loop.

And if you slightly modify this, then you can see that this is actually very similar to a Linked List:

```
 interface CoolList<T, S> {
  next: T | undefined;
  value: S;
}

interface FooDocument extends CoolList<FooDocument, number> {
    next: FooDocument | undefined;
    value: number;
}

class Foo implements FooDocument {
  value: number;
  next: FooDocument | undefined;

  constructor(val: number, next?: FooDocument) {
    this.value = val;
    this.next = next;
  }

  
}

const last = new Foo(3);
const second = new Foo(2, last);
const first = new Foo(1, second);

console.log(first.next?.next?.value); // 3
```

These are generally called recursive data types. Another example of this are ring buffers/circular lists (where the last `next` would point to the first element, rather than undefined), or trees, where you would have multiple `next` properties. It thus makes perfect sense, that Typescript allows this.